# Someone elses repository in my repository list

Tags: github, repository

When I open the main Github page (https://github.com/), in my Repository list, I see the repository which isn't associated with me in any way (circled red on the image)
[image: image here]

I don't know how it got there. When I got to my Settings->Repositories, that repository isn't there. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyUyP.png)

Does anyone know how could that repository get to my Repository list and how could I remove it from the list?

Comment: You have "forked" someone's repository, that is why they appear there

Comment: @AndiDomi I doubt that because on that repository it says that no one has forked it yet?